# How to install Gsnap for audacity ?

Tags: plugins, audacity

I have searched in the internet for an explanation how to install Gsnap as a plugin to audacity. I can not find any information that would settle my insecurity, now I am at a point where I am not even sure if Gsnap is not a windows only program.

Comment: There is a beta version available for Mac and Linux. You can find downloads at GVST's [Mac and Linux porting project page](https://www.gvst.co.uk/portpage.htm). This information was first mentioned by [TheLH](https://askubuntu.com/users/942033/thelh) in an answer here that is now deleted.

Comment: This question (and apparently many others on AskUbuntu) have been scraped by a YouTube user without apparent consent by @RoelVandePaar: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgCp2blRIyc

Answer (score 1):

*[GSnap](http://www.gvst.co.uk/) – free VST pitch-correction* is a Windows only thing.

From the main page

> This site contains several free VST effects and instruments for
>   Windows.

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.*

Comment: actually good news, without it I would spend frustrating hours of research.

Comment: Your answer here appears to be incorrect. GVST had a [beta version for Linux](https://www.gvst.co.uk/portpage.htm) as of 8th Mar 2015. The current beta version is from 2 Aug 2016.

Comment: This answer is not accurate in 2020. There is still a beta version available for linux. https://www.gvst.co.uk/portpage.htm